# Passing arguments to react-template-helper’s “component=”

Tags: meteor, reactjs

In react-template-helper, is there a way to pass an argument into the component?
something like:

```
{{> React component=view 'hello'}}

Template.Home.helpers({
  view: function (bar) {
    console.log(bar)  // logs 'hello'
    ...
    return someComponent;
  }
})
```

Thanks